# Laravel - How to take first name and last name from separate fields and store them in name column in db?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web

So I used `php artisan make:auth` in my project and I am building on top of that. Problem is it has only "name" field and not "firstName" and "lastName" field. Where do I configure those options? I want to take the input from first name and last name and concatenate them with a space between them, then store them as name in my db. Where is the place to do that? Where do I configure my options like if I want to add an address or phone number for my user? I researched a lot and I am really confused with all those traits so please could someone give me some advice on how to proceed with user authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For use name instead of first_name and last_name open `database/migration/create_user_table`
write

`$table->string('name');`

instead of

```
$table->string('first_name');
$table->string('last_name');
```

After that open `app/Http/Controller/Auth/AuthController.php` and then put your code like that

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

if you want to use more fields,write those fields in migration file which is on database/migration and then use those fields in `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` that files's html form,and after that change `AuthController.php` file

Comment: If I leave the $table->string('name'); and add
 'name' => $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'] to my create method, this will create a a new entry with just name (in my db) taken from first_name and last_name right?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-authenticating), you can modify the `AuthController` class in the create method to set which fields are used to create new users.

However, I'd like to ask you to reconsider requiring both fields. Is it really necessary? Does your design spec require it? W3C recommends a single "name" field for better user experience. I understand that some apps will require both, for things like human resources and accounting purposes, but this is worth considering. General consumer type users desire easier forms, so ask as little as possible of your user.

Comment: I'd like to see a citation for this, please.

Comment: I'd question this largely based on the fact that in my use case, I have to address customers by their first or last name. It's absolutely necessary for invoicing, integrated API's that require both fields and many other reasons. I find the W3 spec a bit opinionated here, but I see their rationalisation and empathy for the user.

Comment: The citation requested above is from this extremely detailed document located on the W3C site. Read the whole thing if you have time.  https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names#singlefield